# Infinite loop and i dont know why

Tags: c++

I am working on a school lab and i cant seem to figure out why the code keeps going in to a infinite loop. I know something is wrong with the while statement but i cant see what it is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c = 0, p = 0, prof;

    cout << "Do you like Coke or Pepsi? " << endl;
    cin >> prof;

    //put in data validation


    while (prof != 'q' && prof != 'Q')
    {
        if (prof == 'p')
            p++;
        else if (prof == 'c')
            c++;

        cout << "Do you like Coke or Pepsi? " << endl;
        cin >> prof;
    }


    if (p > c)
        cout << "Pepsi Wins";
    else if (p < c)
        cout << "Coke Wins";

    else
        cout << " It's a tie";

    system("Pause");

}
```

Comment: Why is `prof` and `int` if you are checking for characters?

Comment: Prof is an `int` variable, but you try to store a `char` in it?

Comment: It's wise to verify that your input operations succeed before using their results. See [`std::basic_ios::good()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good). Once an input operation fails, it's likely that all subsequent operations will also fail without waiting for use input unless you clear the error state. Trying to a letter as an `int` will not work, but interpreting a single letter as a `char` will.

Comment: try typing 99 as input

Comment: This is a good example on where using your debugger would've answered the question - as you'd see that prof wasn't what you were expecting it to be.

Comment: Incidentally, having that `cout` ... `cin` sequence in two places suggests that you consider using a `do ... while` loop with the prompt being the first thing in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the variable `prof` should be a `char` not  `int`

```
char prof;
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int c = 0, p = 0;
 char prof;

 cout << "Do you like Coke or Pepsi? " << endl;
 cin >> prof;


 while (prof != 'q' && prof != 'Q')
 {
  if (prof == 'p' && prof == 'P')
   p++;
  else if (prof == 'c' && prof == 'C')
   c++;

  cout << "Do you like Coke or Pepsi? " << endl;
  cin >> prof;
 }
 
 if (p > c)
  cout << "Pepsi Wins" << endl;
 else if (p < c)
  cout << "Coke Wins" << endl;

 else  (p == c);
  cout << " It's a tie";
 
 
 system("Pause");

}

Comment: because it found that `p==c` , what u entered as input ?